# Apply view changes to multiple folders in Outlook 2013 (office 365)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, office365

My company recently switched us over to Office365. I really don't like how the folders are displayed in Outlook (i.e. columns, sorting, etc.) I've set up my inbox the way I want, but really don't want to have to go through each individual folder (I have several dozen) and make the same changes to each. Is there any way to apply the inbox's setup to all my other folders?

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer. Click the View tab, then the Change View button, then Apply Current View to Other Mail Folders.

[image]

Comment: the only thing wrong with this procedure is that you have to click each folder. There should be a option to APPLY TO ALL.